# Make a paginated article (for easier reading on mobile)

Tags: posts, pagination, mobile

I'm looking for some plugin, or perhaps more likely some Javascript package that will make me do something like mobil.idg.se on a phone (select a story, then swipe sideways to read the next part of the story or the next article).

That is, I want a user to compose an article like those paginated reviews you see. (1-intro, 2-specifications, 3-performance, 4-verdict).

That is, when I swipe (or second prize, touch some always-accessible arrow icon), it should trigger some "navigate.Forward()" that Wordpress understands as the next part of the article, and scroll up to the top of that page.

One of the parts of this question is also how a normal Editor user would insert a 'page break' without entering HTML.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are **off-topic** for WPSE. Also, have a look at [the `<!--more-->` tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More).

Comment: Well, I'm not sure a plugin will be required to do this, since at least the side swipe would be some Javascript touch event and effect. I've edited the question a litte. The main question is still how a normal Editor user would insert a 'page break' easily.

Comment: "*One of the parts of this question is also how a normal Editor user would insert a 'page break' without entering HTML.*" - Please have a look at [the Codex entry for the `<!--more-->` tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More).